# Implicit conversion differencies

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

The following works:

```
case class Fraction(d: Int, n: Int) {
  def *(other: Fraction) = Fraction(d * other.d, n * other.n)
}

implicit val int2fraction: Int => Fraction = { x => Fraction(x, 1) }

3 * Fraction(3, 7)
```

The following doesn't:

```
case class Fraction(d: Int, n: Int) {
  def *(other: Fraction) = Fraction(d * other.d, n * other.n)
}

implicit class richInt(x: Int) {
  def int2fraction = Fraction(x, 1)
}

3 * Fraction(3, 7)
```

Why?

Comment: Why would an extension method behave the same as an implicit conversion? Is like asking why `"1" + "1" == "11"` instead of `"2"`

Comment: Because I'm reading verbatim "Instead of providing a conversion function, you can declare RichFile as an implicit class. An implicit class must have a primary constructor with exactly one argument.
That constructor becomes the implicit conversion function." And I don't understand why this is not working in my case

Comment: The implicit conversion is working in the second case, it goes from `Int` into `richInt` but that is pointless in this case so it doesn't apply it. Note, you want a conversion from `Int` into `Fractional` and the second example doesn't provide that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in `3 * Fraction(3, 7)` i.e. `3.*(Fraction(3, 7))`, compiler can see that `Int` doesn't have a method `*`, so the compiler is looking for an implicit conversion from `Int` to a type having `*`.

In the 1st case the compiler finds such implicit conversion, namely `int2fraction`, from `Int` to `Fraction` having `*`.

In the 2nd case the compiler doesn't find such implicit conversion. The primary constructor of `richInt` is an implicit conversion from `Int` to `richInt`, having `int2fraction` but not `*`.

In the 2nd case, `3.int2fraction * Fraction(3, 7)` would work because in such case the compiler would be looking for an implicit conversion from `Int` to a type having `int2fraction`.